# how to update a extended Django User model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have created the user authentication system which includes both the default User model and an extended User model. They are as below:

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d/', null=True)
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    dob = models.DateField(max_length=20, null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    State = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    District = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('profile', kwargs={'id': self.id})


forms.py

class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    Photo = forms.ImageField( max_length=100) 
    dob = forms.DateField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}))
    country = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    State = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    District = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = forms.CharField(max_length=10)

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('Photo', 'dob', 'country', 'State', 'District', 'phone')
```

With the help of the above model and form, I am able to create user, and enter values for those custom model fields and see the user profile. So far so good.

However, I am facing issues while I update those custom fields. I have used the Django's in-built modules to update the default User fields(email). But I am not able to find a way to update those custom fields('dob', 'country', 'State', 'District', 'phone'). Below is the method from views.

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def editUserProfile(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)  # default User profile update
        obj = UserProfile.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
        form1 = UserProfileForm(request.POST or None, instance=obj)  # custom fields update.

        if form.is_valid() and form1.is_valid():
            obj.Photo = form1.cleaned_data['Photo']
            obj.dob = form1.cleaned_data['dob']
            obj.country = form1.cleaned_data['country']
            obj.State = form1.cleaned_data['State']
            obj.District = form1.cleaned_data['District']
            obj.phone = form1.cleaned_data['phone']
            form.save()
            form1.save()
            messages.success(request, f'updated successfully')
            return redirect('/profile1')
        else:
            messages.error(request, f'Please correct the error below.')
    else:
        form = UserProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        form1 = UserProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
    return render(request, "authenticate\\editProfilePage.html", {'form': form, 'form1': form1})
```

I have an update button on my profile page, on clicking I could only see the "email" field with pre-populated data to update(I can update this default field successfully).

I have seen other stackoverflow posts, but they are not helping.

I am not able to figure out the mistakes.

Please help

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in this line

```
obj = UserProfile.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
```

here left id is id from UserProfile model. so it will be something like this

```
obj = UserProfile.objects.get(user__id=request.user.id)
```